Positioning button in upper right corner SwiftUI
I'm am new to SwiftUI and running into trouble with getting my stacks in the right order to position a button in the upper right corner.
Here is what I have so far:
import SwiftUI

struct MainMenu: View {

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("RangeCattle1")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
            VStack {
                Button("Management") {
                    
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                .buttonBorderShape(.capsule)
                .tint(.red)
            
                Button("Calculator") {
                    
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                .buttonBorderShape(.capsule)
                .tint(.red)
                
            }
            Spacer()
            .font(.title)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    MainMenu()
}

I have tried adding an Hstack inside the Z but it only positions it behind the existing buttons or if I add a spacer it pushes it to the left.
Any suggestions? I would like it to be in the upper right hand corner with the existing buttons where they are at.
[EDIT]
I made a few changes and this is where I am at.  The logout button needs to be upper right hand corner.
import SwiftUI

struct MainMenu: View {

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("RangeCattle1")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
            VStack {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Button("Logout") {
                            
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                        .buttonBorderShape(.capsule)
                        .tint(.red)
                    }
                }
                VStack {
                    Button("Management") {
                        
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                    .buttonBorderShape(.capsule)
                    .tint(.red)
                    Button("Calculator") {
                        
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                    .buttonBorderShape(.capsule)
                    .tint(.red)
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    MainMenu()
}

[Edit - V2]
import Amplify
import Authenticator
import AWSCognitoAuthPlugin
import SwiftUI


@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    init() {
        do {
            try Amplify.add(plugin: AWSCognitoAuthPlugin())
            try Amplify.configure()
        } catch {
            print("Unable to configure Amplify \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Authenticator(
                headerContent: {
                    Image("Final")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal) { size, axis in
                            size * 0.8
                        }
                },
                footerContent: {
                    Text("© 2024 The PATG Group, Inc. All Rights Reserved")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                }
            ) { _ in
                
                    MainMenu()
                }
            }
        }
    
    struct MainMenu: View {
        var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                HStack {
                    Button("Logout") {
                        // Need Code here
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                    .buttonBorderShape(.capsule)
                    .tint(.red)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topTrailing)
                .padding()
                
                VStack(spacing: 40) {
                    Button("Management") {
                        // Need Code here
                    }
                    
                    Button("Calculator") {
                        // Need Code here
                    }

                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                .buttonBorderShape(.capsule)
                .tint(.red)
                .font(.title)
            
            }
            .background {
                Image("RangeCattle1")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
            }
        }
    }

    #Preview {
        MainMenu()
    }
}


The latest edit includes the primary login view which once that is complete, takes you to the next view.  Not sure if that's the correct way to do it, but it is working.
I wanted to give everyone a chance to chime in one last time before I marked it complete.

So you want these two buttons to be at the top-trailing instead of center on the ZStack, right?

I want those two centered in the middle with a third button in the upper right hand corner.

Did you try .overlay(alignment: .topTrailing) within ZStack?

I did, it throws wrong argument error.

I would suggest un-nesting the Logout button and showing it as a direct child of the ZStack. Then:

Apply .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topTrailing) to the Logout button, to push it into the top-right corner.
You might want to add some trailing padding to the Logout button too, so that it stays away from the trailing display edge.
I would suggest setting the Image as .background to the ZStack, so that it does not affect the layout of the ZStack.
UIScreen.main and .edgesIgnoringSafeArea are both deprecated. The .frame is not needed anyway when the image is applied as background (because the content of the ZStack is already maximum size). Instead of .edgesIgnoringSafeArea, use ignoresSafeArea.
The modifiers being set on the other buttons can be applied (once) to the VStack that contains them, instead of duplicating the modifiers for each button. In fact, if the ZStack is not going to have any other content then the modifiers could be applied to the ZStack instead and removed from the Logout button too.

ZStack {
    Button("Logout") {}
        .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        .buttonBorderShape(.capsule)
        .tint(.red)
        .padding(.trailing)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topTrailing)

    VStack {
        Button("Management") {}
        Button("Calculator") {}
    }
    .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
    .buttonBorderShape(.capsule)
    .tint(.red)
}
.background {
    Image("RangeCattle1")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill()
        .ignoresSafeArea()
}


Thanks Benzy, I'll post my latest in a second.  I have this issue resolved I believe but wanted you to see the final code first, before marking it complete.  Please, if there are any other suggestions I'm all ears.

@DouglasW.Palme All looks good except the background image, which is setting an unnecessary frame and (still) using deprecated code. Suggest copying exactly as provided in the answer here (see also notes in answer). If this doesn't work because of the header/footer in Authenticator then apply the image as background to Authenticator instead. BTW, the padding you are adding to the Logout button will also move it down from the top-right corner, you will notice I only gave it trailing padding. Ps. thanks for accepting the answer!
